# Mailx Configuration Without mailrc

Tags: linux, smtp, redhat, postfix-mta, mailx

i am using mailx command in Red Hat,
i use this command:

```
mailx -r 'boss@comp.com' -s 'Email Send' 'user@comp.com' < file_body
```

I don't have a local configuration for SMTP Server
I don't have for my user the ~/mailrc
The mail is sent successfully but i don't know the way that it used...

I am using the postfix configuration in /etc/postfix and i use their commands like mailq and so on.

Which configuration it Use?? 
Use it the /etc/resolv.conf where it found the smtp server?
use it the route on /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts ????

Answer (score 0):

Your local system is probably connecting to your ISP's SMTP server, or possibly straight to the MX for `comp.com`.